# Scaling an image to crop in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview

I am working on an android application that allows the user to crop an image. I have tried this code to scale the image to crop. But when I try to resize the area to crop, it moves both horizontally and vertically, only allowing to crop a square area. I want it to work in such a way that when I move it vertically it doesn't move vertically

> ```
>       intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);           
>         intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
>         intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
>         intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
>         intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
>         intent.putExtra("scale", true);
>         intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
>         intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following code, then you can crop any size

```
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);  
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
```

Comment: hi,i tried this, it still scales an image only in the form of a square

Comment: what device do you use? it works well in my galaxy note2. how about removing scale and scaleUpIfNeeded?

Comment: I was trying it on the emulator. I changed it to                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);  
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1.5);                                                               it works great now.

Comment: REMOVE this two parameters

Comment: ohhh sorry didn't see it .Thanks